# How to measure the number of direct clicks to a file in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking, measure

Say I have a file in my website: `https://example.com/sample.pdf`

Is there a way to track how many people clicking on the link, similarly how regular links are tracked? The article [Additional kinds of measurement - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012044?hl=en#Download) suggests me to measure clicks as Events. However, if I send the *direct link* to the viewers, there will be no script to be fired.

Comment: Google Analytics isn't the right tool for the job.  I don't think you can add your tracking snippet to a PDF document.   Do you have access logs you can use instead?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree.  I wonder if a workaround by putting a link to an html file (with the Analytics code embedded) which then calls the PDF would be sufficient for the OP?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, but having it included in the Google Analytics report would be convenient. Also, I would like to have different tracking links for different targets. I think the idea of putting it into an HTML file is good. Definitely better than having one redirect to the file

Comment: @davidgo thanks for you suggestion. It works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a blank HTML file, then embed the PDF inside it:

```
    <embed src="path/to/file" width="100%" height="100%"  type="application/pdf">
```

For your convenience, here is my template:

```
<head>
<title>CHANGE THIS TEXT</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT">
<meta name="keywords" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT">
<meta name="author" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta property="og:title" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT" />
<meta property="og:description" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT" />
<meta property="og:image" content="CHANGE THIS TEXT" />

<!-- INSERT Google Tag Manager script -->
<!-- INSERT Facebook Like script -->    

<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .phone {
        font-size: large;
    }
    .desktop{
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .phone {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<div class="phone">
    CHANGE THIS TEXT
    <a href="https://xkcd.com/1110/"><img src="https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/c/c7/click_and_drag.png" width="100%" alt="From the stories, I expected the world to be sad.
    And it was
    And I expected it to be wonderful.
    It was.
    I just didn't expect it to be so big."></a>
</div>

<div class="desktop">
    <embed src="CHANGE THIS TEXT" width="100%" height="100%"  type="application/pdf">
</div>
<br>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="CHANGE THIS TEXT" data-width="" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share="true" ></div>
```